# Check for ISO_C_BINDING usage in Fortran calling C function

Tags: c, pointers, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I've asked a few questions on `ISO_C_BINDING`, and I made a routine. Since I've always made quite a few mistakes dealing with Fortran POINTER, I want to make it sure that there is no mistake or some weird point that is not a recommended way.

(Fortran part)

```
program test
  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none
  interface
    subroutine get_value_array(in, num) bind(C, name='get_value_Array')
      use iso_c_binding
      implicit none
      type(C_PTR),           intent(inout)  :: in
      integer(C_INT), value, intent(in)     :: num
    end subroutine
  end interface

  real(C_DOUBLE), allocatable, target  :: array(:)
  real(C_DOUBLE),              pointer :: array_fptr(:)
  type(C_PTR)                          :: array_cptr

  integer :: array_len

  allocate(array(12))
  array_len = size(array,1)

  array_cptr = C_LOC(array)

  call get_value_array (array_cptr, array_len)

  call C_F_POINTER(array_cptr, array_fptr, [array_len])

  print *, 'array_fptr'
  print *, array_fptr

  print *, 'array'
  print *, array

end program
```

(C part)

```
void get_value_Array(double **in, int num) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    (*in)[i] = i+1;
  } 
}
```

(Output)

```
 array_fptr
   1.00000000000000        2.00000000000000        3.00000000000000
   4.00000000000000        5.00000000000000        6.00000000000000
   7.00000000000000        8.00000000000000        9.00000000000000
   10.0000000000000        11.0000000000000        12.0000000000000
 array
   1.00000000000000        2.00000000000000        3.00000000000000 
   4.00000000000000        5.00000000000000        6.00000000000000 
   7.00000000000000        8.00000000000000        9.00000000000000 
   10.0000000000000        11.0000000000000        12.0000000000000
```

To make it sure, the process is

1. `array_cptr` is associated to `array` with `C_LOC` function. (Maybe 'associate' is not a proper terminology here since it's Fortran pointer related terminology. What should I call it?)
2. `array` gets modified when I call `get_value_array`, since the subroutine(or C function) modifies where the `array_cptr` points to.
3. `array_fptr` is associated to `array` through `array_cptr` when I call `C_F_POINTER`

And finally `array_cptr` and `array_fptr` are different object(?) to each other, while pointing at the same target `array`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statements in the question are ambiguous.  To be precise.

1. With the Fortran statement `array_cptr = C_LOC(array)`, `array_cptr` is assigned the C address of `array`.
2. When `get_value_array` is invoked, the value of `array` is ultimately modified by the C function.  The Fortran code also makes allowance for the subroutine (or C function) to modify the C address stored in `array_cptr` - the dummy argument is declared as INTENT(INOUT) and does not have the VALUE attribute, and consistent with that the C function takes the pointer to the array by reference (i.e. the C formal parameter is declared as a pointer to pointer to double).  But the C function does not make such modifications to the C address stored in `array_cptr`.  For the code shown, there is an unnecessary level of indirection.
3. The Fortran code associates `array_fptr` with the thing referenced by the C address in `array_cptr`.  Because the C address in `array_cptr` has not been been changed by the C function, array_fptr continues to be associated with `array`.  Execution of C_F_POINTER in this case does not change the state of the program.

`array_cptr` is a different thing to `array_fptr` - but they have the same target  (array_cptr is an object, array_fptr is associated with an object - pointers in Fortran are not objects in their own right, unlike in C).

Comment: Thank you, your reply helped me a lot in clarifying things in the code. With the '2.' in your answer, you mean that the ```array_cptr```being declared as INTENT(INOUT) is unnecessary since its value itself does not change? (While the ```array``` stored where the address points to gets modified). Setting ```array_cptr``` as INTENT(IN) indeed caused no problem, while setting it ```VALUE, INTENT(IN)``` caused segfault.

Other than that, my code is mostly out of error, isn't it? (The unnecessary indirection here is because my target C function takes ```**``` as its argument.)

Comment: Yes.  If you added VALUE you would need to remove a layer of indirection from the C function.